# ¿Como arreglar error de Angular 2 en Eclipse?

Tags: angular, eclipse, ide

Al intentar crear un proyecto de Angular en eclipse sale este error y no deja abrir el proyecto. ¿Por qué se esta generando? ¿Cómo se puede solucionar?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Se debe descargar Typescript 2.3+ desde Marketplace en Eclipse, al instalarlo ya funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitar incorporar un pluging adicional en Eclipse que lo puedes descargar desde

> https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angular-eclipse

también hay información adicional, espero te fuera útil